# Как просматривать только первые 20 строк при создании перекрестного запроса?

Tags: sql, access

Как просмотреть только первые 20 строк при создании перекрестного запроса в `Access`?
Нужно использовать первые 20 записей.
Перекрестный запрос:

```
TRANSFORM Count([Копия успеваемость].[ФИО студента]) AS [Count-ФИО студента]
SELECT [Копия успеваемость].[№ зачетной книжки]
FROM [Копия успеваемость]
GROUP BY [Копия успеваемость].[№ зачетной книжки]
PIVOT [Копия успеваемость].[ФИО студента];
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста вопрос. Укажите какую БД вы используете. И очень желательно привести пример запроса о котором идет речь.

Comment: Не знаю что такое TRANSFORM, но с простыми SELECT-ами должно сработать SELECT TOP 20 [Копия успеваемости] ...

Answer (score 5):

Для MSSQL это будет вариант с `TOP`, а вообще, различные вариации можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)

```
SQL Server / MS Access Syntax
SELECT TOP number|percent column_name(s)
FROM table_name;

MySQL Syntax
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
LIMIT number;

Oracle Syntax
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE ROWNUM <= number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Например для `MySQL` добавить в конце запроса.

```
LIMIT 0,20
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Если добавить в конец моего запроса, пишет ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо таблицы [Копия успеваемость] используйте запрос, который ограничит набор записей.